# "let" command does not print the result

Tags: bash

I'm learning shell programming. I checked for let command. I'm trying to use it within echo like we do use expr but I'm not understanding how can I possibly do that

```
num1=30
num2=20
echo "Sum is `let $num1 + $num2` "
```

Answer (score 1):

`let`, `expr` and backticks have been phased out of use during the last two decades of shell programming.  They are still there and you can use them, but there are nowadays easier, handier and safer constructs to use:

- `let` may be replaced by `(( ... ))`
- `expr` may be replaced by `$(( ... ))`
- backticks may be replaced by `$( ... )`. These nest a lot better and quoting works intuitively.

So, with that in mind, your script may be rewritten

```
#!/bin/sh

num1=30
num2=20

printf 'Sum is %d\n' "$(( num1 + num2 ))"
```

Or, if you're happy to output variable strings with `echo`:

```
echo "Sum is $(( num1 + num2 ))"
```

instead of that last line with `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it does not work for echo, just work for assignments:

```
let a=1+2
echo $a
3
```

try:

```
let a=$num1+$num2 && echo "Sum is $a"
```

or, easier:

```
echo "Sum is $((num1+num2))"

echo "Sum is $(($num1+$num2))"
```

Comment: `$` not needed within `$(( ... ))`.

Comment: yes, $(( ... )) is needed.

    winston@winston:~$ echo "Sum is $num1+$num2"
    Sum is 30+20

Comment: The `$` _within_ `$(( ... ))` are not needed: `echo "sum is $(( num1+num2 ))`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Which shell are we talking about? Your question is tagged *shell*, which usually refers to the Posix shell, and it has no `let`.

Second, bash and Zsh do have let, but (as you can easily see by trying it out), the command doesn't print anything on standard output, so `let 4711` will always be replaced by the null string.